# Lightbox2 in Web Template

Tags: templates, lightbox

I'm using a template: http://dribbble.com/shots/333369-Atlas-a-Free-HTML-Template-PSD and want to add Lightbox to it. The code around the img file looks like this right now:

```
<li data-tags="Web Design">
<a href="#">
  <span class="portfoliohover">
    <h1 class="porthover1">Cool Rollover Titles</h1>
    <h1 class="porthover2">As well as some nifty sub-titles</h1>
  </span>
  <img src="images/portfolio/work2.png" alt="" />
</a>
</li>
```

If you go through all of the directions on the Lightbox website, change # to the source img, and put in `rel="lightbox"` in the `<a>` tag, it should work, right? I tried, but it didn't do anything, even when I click it.

Comment: Are you using this lightbox http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/ ?

Comment: Nope, using it directly from http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/
Should I try using the one you mentioned?

Comment: Have you included the js files? If you are using google chrome, try to use the [javascript console error](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console) and see if something is broke.

Comment: even if your not using chrome, you can just look at the console in safari, chrome, firefox. In chrome to get there, use right click, and then inspect element, and then click on console, refresh the page, and see if it shows an error.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see any mention of rel="lightbox" when I inspect elements, but it's not giving me any errors. I'm also using Dreamweaver, and it seems perfectly happy with the code.